# Insert data from an Array into different HTML Divs

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have created 5 divs that have the same id and class with a loop. I'm now trying to populate each div with a different headline from the News API. I have managed to populate the first div with the data but I'm struggling how to insert data into the others.

Here is my attempt

```
// Fetch Data from API
fetch(req)
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then(r => {
    const container = document.getElementsByClassName('postWrap')[0];

    // Create div elements
    for(i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) {
      // Create title div
      const titleDiv = document.createElement('div');
      container.appendChild(titleDiv);

      // Set ID & Class
      titleDiv.id = 'postTitle';
      titleDiv.classList.add('post-body');

      // Post title data from array into div
      let post = r.articles[i];
      let title = post.title;
      document.getElementById('postTitle').innerHTML = title;
    }
  });
```

Comment: Use `titleDiv.id = 'postTitle-' + i;` because IDs are unique. Also, replace `document.getElementById('postTitle').innerHTML = title;` with  `titleDiv.innerHTML = title;`.

Comment: #Ids **must be unique**. When a browser is sent to search an #id, it will find the first one it sees. Knowing that #ids are unique the browser logically assumes that there is nothing else to find. Change or remove the duplicate #ids it is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id of DOM should be unique. Same id of DOMs is not recommended.

Your div instances are created by your javascript code, so you can use those instance directly but get from ID.

```
const titleDiv = document.createElement('div');

/* Omitted.... */

// Post title data from array into div
let post = r.articles[i];
let title = post.title;
titleDiv.innerHTML = title;
```